# How to create file image from blob?

Tags: javascript, blob

I'm new to Javascript and have been doing some research  on BLOBs, and in theory this code should create a new file image but nothing happens,  any suggestions?

```
var blob =  new Blob(["hello", "StackExchange"], {type: "text/plain"});
```

I've tried to save it with:

```
saveAs(blob, "C:/Users/me/Desktop/BLOOB_EXAMPLE.txt"); // nothing
```

and

```
var fs = new FileSaver(blob,"C:/Users/me/Desktop/BLOOB_EXAMPLE.txt"); // nothing
```

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: What environment hosts your JS code? Browsers don't provide filesystem access to JS.

Comment: The [File Writer API](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-writer-api/) you appear to be trying to use was only ever intended to write to a sandboxed file system, so you can't use it to specify a particular directory on the hard disk. More importantly, work on it has been abandoned.